# Make apache read a new virtual host automatically (no restart)

Tags: apache-2.2

I need to have apache read a new file under `sites-available`, but I don't want to have to restart apache every time one is added. The dynamic hosts function would not work for me due to the way the directories are set up on my server to allow for mass deployment of my software. I don't think that `shell_exec` will work because apache runs from `www-data`, and that user doesn't have access to reload httpd with `/etc/init.d/httpd reload`. I need to be able to run virtual hosts dynamically, without restarting apache completely.

Answer (score 8):

> I need to have apache read a new file under sites-available, but I
>   don't want to have to restart apache every time one is added.

[image]

> The dynamic hosts function would not work for me due to the way the
>   directories are set up on my server to allow for mass deployment of my
>   software.

[image]

> that user doesn't have access to reload httpd with /etc/init.d/httpd
>   reload

[image]

> I need to be able to run virtual hosts dynamically, without restarting
>   apache completely.

You have painted yourself into a corner and now all of the tools provided for situations like this are out of reach. You need to figure out a way to make it work using one of the methods you mentioned. Probably using dynamic hosts and re-implementing your application's filesystem structure. *"But I can't because cats and planets and life and the universe!"* Okay, I get it, whatever. I still suspect it's likely out of true with good systems/application design patterns, but I'll leave it alone. If it's justifiable, then `service reload` should be made to fit the situation in some way. If nothing works, then everything is broken so let's go play hopscotch.

Answer (score -5):

All I had to do was add the user that runs the webserver to the sudousers file and allow them to reload apache.

Comment: Then why did you say "that user doesn't have access to reload httpd with /etc/init.d/httpd reload".... In Sys Admin terms that means 'he is not authorized to by organizational policy'. If you could give him access then your post was unnecessary in the first place.